# Validation will not function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have added validation to my model, but when I try to enforce it in my controller, it seems to not detect that the code is invalid and goes to the incorrect view.

My thoughts is that for some reason it is not looking at the obj and bypasses this, but I cannot find a way to get it to inspect for me.

Can anyone help me?

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace messageBoard.Models
{
public class Messages
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Sender { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Receiver { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Form { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }

}
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TLA_Message_Board.Models;

namespace TLA_Message_Board.Controllers
{
public class MessagesController : Controller
{
    // GET: Messages
    public ActionResult Load()
    {
        Messages obj = new Messages {
            Sender = "Ross McKenzie",
            Receiver = "Noah McKenzie",
            Year = 9,
            StartDate = new DateTime(2018, 06, 28),
            Expiry = new DateTime(2018, 06, 29),
            Title = "Title Test",
            Message = "This is the first message for the test of the internal message board."
        };
        return View("Messages",obj);

    }

    public ActionResult Enter()
    {

        return View("EnterMessages");
    }
    public ActionResult Submit()
    {

        Messages obj = new Messages();
        obj.Sender = Request.Form["Sender"];
        obj.Receiver = Request.Form["Receiver"];

        string year = Request.Form["Year"];
        obj.Year = Int32.Parse(year);

        string start = Request.Form["StartDate"];
        DateTime startParse = DateTime.Parse(start);
        obj.StartDate = startParse;

        string expiry = Request.Form["Expiry"];
        DateTime expiryParse = DateTime.Parse(expiry);
        obj.StartDate = expiryParse;

        obj.Title = Request.Form["Title"];
        obj.Message = Request.Form["Message"];

         if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Messages", obj);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("EnterMessages");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to explicitly check the validation API.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, how would I go about doing that?  I am a novice to C'# and MVC

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation#how-validation-occurs-in-the-create-view-and-create-action-method

Comment: Thanks for the link, but what I am reading does not help me to solve why the validation is not working server side.  Any pointers?

Comment: You need to check `ModelState.IsValid`.  The validation system does not do anything automatically.

Comment: I used this in an if with model.state (see edited code), still nothing worked

Comment: You need to actually use model binding, by adding a model parameter to your action method.  Do not use `Request.Form`.

Comment: If your `public ActionResult Submit()` is actually the `[HttpPost]` method, then change it to `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Submit(Messages model)` and the model will be bound and any validation errors will be added (your current model will never be invalid because you are not using model binding)